# Calculate remaining time from end time that lies on next date

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, date-time

Shift begins in evening and ends at 05:00 in the morning

I am looking to calculate in real time, how much time is left till end of shift.

I have been using =NOW() in hh:mm format to calculate and end of shift left it at 05:15 in hh:mm as shown below. Obviously end of shift will be +1 day from start of shift date.

Any way to go around calculating how many hours left almost like a countdown?

[image]

Comment: Apply `[H]:mm` time format on formula cell, it will consider time if exceeds 24 Hrs.

Comment: @RajeshS sorry, I forgot to add that I did that and it came back as error

Comment: since you have not shared the Screen Shot or WB then right now difficult to say about the reason,, but what I've tried `Shift Start Time: 28-06-2021  06:00:00 PM`  &  the `Shift End Time 29-06-2021  05:15:00 AM` ,,, time I've use to get Remaining hrs `28-06-2021  08:00:00 PM` ,,, it's `NOW()` and getting `9:15` ,,,  Start & End Time cell Format are `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`  and formula cell has `[h]:mm` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try this also:*

[image]

- Formula in cell AG14:

  `=TODAY()+AG10+(24/24)-AG11`

**N.B.**

- cell AG11 has `NOW()`, and cell format is `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` it may be `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm AM/PM` also.
- Where `AG+(24/24)` adds 24 Hours to `Today()` & returns `30/06/2021 05:15:00`, and is adjustable.
- Cell AG14 has cell format `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Glad to help you @Teodros IV ,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 2):

Here is my sample, I set cell with "Now()" as a date format, set the cell with "05:15" as hh:mm.

[image]

Then I use the formula `=IF(B2>(TODAY()+TIME(5,0,0)),(24+TODAY()+TIME(5,15,0))-B2,(TODAY()+TIME(5,15,0))-B2)` to get the remaining time.

[image]

Please remember to press F9 to refresh time.

Comment: Nice one @Emily ,,, you get +10 ☺

Comment: @RajeshS  Thank you very much ~~~. the same to you.